# Highcharts columns overlapped

Tags: highcharts, overlapping

can you tell me how to avoid this overlapping issue using the Highcharts libraries?

[Here the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d58vwagf/1/)

You see there are 2 column overlapped, and even the tickers label are overlapped!

```
chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },title: {
            text: 'title'
        },plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                minPointLength: 2
            }
        },xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'date'
            },
            tickPositions:  categoriesGrafico,
            labels:{
                rotation: -90,
                formatter:function(){
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y',this.value);
                }
            },
            reversed: true,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%d/%m/%Y',
            }
        },yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'value'
            },
            min: 0
        },
    series: seriesGrafico
});
```

I've read a lot of posts on the web, and tried a lot of options, but without a solution.

Thanks you so much

Comment: You've told the chart to put them where they are, so your options are going to be limited in resolving.  As Sebastian says in his answer, the point range is a solution - but you'll have to accept very thin columns if you want your data to be that close together and not overlap.

Comment: yes i tried... and the columns became really thin! :D

Comment: Yes. But those are your options if you want to be able to plot values that are so close together - overlap, really thin columns, or make the chart so wide that the values aren't so close together. Or, forget datetime and go with categories instead.

Comment: I see... there should be an option to place datetime values as categories, not in scale, but with an equal distance between each tick positions

Comment: That is actually the default in Highstock - http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal ; option has not made it into the highcharts core though it seems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have two tick so close. The solution can be setting [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) or modify tickPositions.

Comment: Yes it seems that pointRange is the only one solution in my case... Since displayed data can have differernt range, I should calculate it first, as the minimum distance in millisecond between two consecutive points... right?! :D

Comment: even if the tickers overlapping issue keeps going... hmmmm

Comment: In my opinion there is not a solution. Even if I set a pointRange of one day (in millisecond), the columns not overlap, but the tickers label keep everlapping when they are rotate in 90°... Maybe with categories instead of datetime... Idk I should try it

Comment: The problem is that this two ticks are so close, so in this case you can try to move labels by x/y parameters http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.y